# How can I improve the performance to collect the information I need from this Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

First time here and a beginner in Pandas so I'll try to be as clear as possible.
I have a data set that contains a column "Name" that contain child and parent.
The parent row give me a start and a stop value and with that I know what are the child associated with this parent.

My data

```
In[64]: df
Out[64]: 
      Name  Start  Stop Id
0    child      2     4  x
1    child      5     6  x
2    child      7     8  x
3   parent      1    10  x
4    child     12    15  y
5    child     15    16  y
6    child     16    19  y
7    child     20    22  y
8    child     23    24  y
9   parent     11    25  y
10   child     27    28  z
11   child     29    34  z
12  parent     26    35  z
```

What I want is a dataframe for each parent that will contain all the child row.
The child start and end value must be between the range of value found in the parent and the id needs to match as well.
**UPDATE**: Multiple parent can have the same Id.

I have a working strategy that goes like this:

- Build a dataframe containing all the parent row.
- Iterate through all the row of this new dataframe
- For each row, check the start,stop and id and test all the row of my source dataframe if it's a match
- Append this into a new dataframe and insert into a list of dataframe.

The code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':  ['child','child','child','parent','child','child','child','child','child','parent','child','child','parent'],
        'Start': [2,5,7,1,12,15,16,20,23,11,27,29,26],
        'Stop':  [4,6,8,10,15,16,19,22,24,25,28,34,35],
        'Id':  ['x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y','y','y','z','z','z']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dfParent = df[df['Name'].str.contains('parent', regex=False)]

dfList = [] # Creating an empty series of dataframe

for index, row in dfParent.iterrows():           
        # Create a new dataframe that will contain all child of a parent                
        dfTemp = pd.DataFrame()        
        dfTemp = dfTemp.append(df.loc[(df['Start'] > row['Start']) & (df['Stop'] < row['Stop']) & (df['Id'] == row['Id'])])                   
        dfList.append(dfTemp)
```

---

```
dfList
Out[61]: 
[    Name  Start  Stop Id
 0  child      2     4  x
 1  child      5     6  x
 2  child      7     8  x,
     Name  Start  Stop Id
 4  child     12    15  y
 5  child     15    16  y
 6  child     16    19  y
 7  child     20    22  y
 8  child     23    24  y,
      Name  Start  Stop Id
 10  child     27    28  z
 11  child     29    34  z]
```

The result is ok but the performance are **terrible** when I use my real data set (~500 000 row).

So my question is: Do you have any tips on how I can start improving this code?
Thanks!

Comment: Does each `Id` only have exactly one `parent`?

Comment: Is a Pandas Dataframe really the right data structure for this? Where does the data come from, what is the context here?

Comment: Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: @Quang Hoang, No, the same id can be found in multiple parent, sorry for not mentioning it earlier.

Comment: @AMC I don't know if Pandas dataframe is the way to go. I guess I'll have my answer if people think it's not something possible. The context of my data is function calls. The child can be seen as all the function called during the parent function execution. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @RoyalGre So the data is a graph, right? I'm not sure what the ideal data structure in Python for this particular case is, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each `Id` only has one `parent`:

```py
dfList = []
for k, d in df.groupby('Id'):
    start, stop = d.loc[d["Name"] == 'parent', ['Start', 'Stop']].iloc[0]

    dfList.append(d[d["Name"].eq('child') & d["Start"].ge(start) & d["Stop"].le(stop)])
```

Or you can do a `merge` and query:

```
(df[df["Name"].eq('parent')]
   .merge(df[df["Name"].eq('child')], on='Id',
          suffixes=['_p','_c'])
   .query('Start_p<=Start_c<=Stop_c<=Stop_p')
)
```